# Airflow deployment on fargate(ECS) tasks

Tags: airflow, amazon-ecs, continuous-deployment, aws-fargate, aws-code-deploy

We have an airflow that is deployed on ECS cluster on AWS. The tasks are running on Fargate. It's using the default **rolling deployment**.

We have some **long running** tasks. What happens is whenever we update the task definition, the current running tasks is killed, and new task container is initialized with the new image(defined in task definition), which is not desired since the task running for 1 hour or more already.

We are interested in see if there's some ways that the task definition update won't kill the running tasks or the update can wait till the running tasks finished then update.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue with our deployment. We handled the issue by using `desired_count`. For example, if we set it to `2` and you release a new image of the application, you will have a task running at all times as only one will be upgraded at one time.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service#desired_count

Also, if you do this you will to make some changes to healthcheck.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service#deployment_minimum_healthy_percent

If you set `desired_count = 2`

You will need to set `deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 50`